# Fixed string size in C#

Tags: c#, string

The short question:
Is it possible to create a fixed size string in C#?
I know that in VB it's possible declaring something like this: str AS string * 20

The long story:
I need to read a binary file that contains a 20 byte field into a string. I read the content of the file into an object (class). I want to limit the strings in the object in the class definition.

Thank you very much for your concern.

roi

Comment: How are you reading the file?

Comment: That only works in VB 6. It's not possible in VB.NET, either. The CLR doesn't support fixed-length strings. Why do you need to limit the size? If the file you're reading is only 20 bytes, that's how long the resulting string will be.

Comment: I did not mentioned all my problem in order to limit the text of my question: The file is binary which containd menu item details: Size (long), BasicButtonHeight (long) BasicBurronWidth (long) Row (long), Columns (long), ImagesPath (string 20 bytes long) and, LabelsFilePath (also 20 bytes long string). The file was written for VB6 aplication, and I need to convert the data for C# application.

Answer (score 5):

You could declare and fill a fixed size char array, and then pass that to the String objects constructor to make the string from that.

`var newString = new string(theCharArray);`

Answer (score 4):

You should create a property of type `string` that checks `value.Length` in the setter and truncates it or throws an exception.

Comment: I understand that it is not possible to directly declare a fixed size string in C# ?

Comment: It doesn't actually make sense to declare a fixed-length string.  A string is a string.  What are you doing?

Comment: Im trying to extract binary created for VB6 application to C# object.

Comment: @SLaks  Just because the language/environment doesn't support fixed length strings does not mean it "doesn't make sense"   There are many applications in which a fixed length string is the right tool for the job and using a variable length string puts an extra burden on every programmer who touches the object to "get it right."

Comment: @DaleWilson: True; I meant that it doesn't make sense within the CLR type system.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `'StringBuilder'` for your issue.

Comment: StringBuffer is Java, it's StringBuilder in C#.

Comment: Actually its StringBuilder in both java and c#. StringBuffer is javas old, synchronized version of StringBuilder.

Comment: StringBuffer is definitely present at MSVC++ environment (maybe a little bit obsolete). Anyways, it's not the very important IMHO, since all of these classes provide roughly the same semantics, differing mostly in compat.

Comment: Care to elaborate how to do that with StringBuilder?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the VBFixedString attribute.  This is an information-only attribute and does not restrict the actual length of the string.  It is used for communicating with API calls that expect a VB6-style fixed-length string.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x14b6s77.aspx

Comment: Thank you - but I want to use "pure" C# objects